# .NET: Async: return value

Tags: c#

I have 2 async functions that I execute and return an integer. When I try to access the return value, the IDE complains that the tasks are void type, not int type.

```
private async Task<int> func01(int _i1, int _i2)
{
    return await Task.Run(async () => {                
            await Task.Delay(1000);
            return 1;
        });

}

private async Task<int> func02(string _i1, string_i2)
{
    return await Task.Run(async () => {                
            await Task.Delay(3000);
            return 1;
        });

}

Task _t1 = func01(1, 3);
Task _t2 = func02("Hello", "World");
int _r1 = await _t1; //here, IDE says that _t1 and _t2 are void types
int _r2 = await _t2;
```

How do I return a value from an async task?

Comment: You are upcasting the return values of the functions to `Task` instead of `Task<int>`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because return type of functions are not `Task`, its return `Task<int>`. So you have to use;

```
Task<int> _t1 = func01(1, 3);
Task<int> _t2 = func02("Hello", "World");
```

**Tip:** You can also use `var` keyword. I think its better.

```
var _t1 = func01(1, 3);
var _t2 = func02("Hello", "World");
```

Comment: `var` will work too. I personally prefer declaring all local variables as `var`

Comment: I update answer.